# Inserting date into SQLite table

Tags: sql, macos, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I am new to SQL, and I want to create a student table with student dates of birth in it. Here's my code. I am running SQLite on Visual Studio Code

```
create table student
(std_code             varchar(8),
std_fname            varchar(15)    constraint student_std_lname_nn not null,
std_lname            varchar(15)    constraint student_std_fname_nn not null,
std_gend              varchar(8),   
maj_code              varchar(10)   constraint student_maj_code_fk references                 
major (maj_code),
std_dob                date, 
constraint student_std_code_pk primary key (std_code));

insert into student values ('S01', 'Michael', 'Jordan', 'M', 'FINC', date(1962- 
03-10));
insert into student values ('S02', 'Charles', 'Barkley', 'M', null, date(1964- 
09-12));
```

The code runs without error, but when I run `SELECT * FROM student`, the dates look all wrong. [image]

Any help fixing the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The reason you're seeing those weird dates, btw, is because `date()`, given just a numeric argument (like 1964 minus 9 minus 12), treats it as a julian day. More information about [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). All those varchars in the table definition make me think you should read up on [sqlite data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), too.

Comment: You are missing single quotes around the date constant values.  I view this is a simple typographical error and vote to close for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotation `'` contain your date string.

> date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)

So you need to pass `DateTime` string be the parameter.

```
insert into student values ('S01', 'Michael', 'Jordan', 'M', 'FINC',
                            '1962-03-10');
insert into student values ('S02', 'Charles', 'Barkley', 'M', null, 
                            '1964-09-12');
```

or just use `Date` string

```
insert into student values ('S01', 'Michael', 'Jordan', 'M', 'FINC',
                            '1962-03-10');
insert into student values ('S02', 'Charles', 'Barkley', 'M', null, 
                            '1964-09-12');
```

**Query #1**

```
select * from student;

| std_code | std_fname | std_lname | std_gend | maj_code | std_dob    |
| -------- | --------- | --------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- |
| S01      | Michael   | Jordan    | M        | FINC     | 1962-03-10 |
| S02      | Charles   | Barkley   | M        |          | 1964-09-12 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8sLQJ8pJXV8W5DbeAYAfKn/2)